# Disable default selected tab

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm using [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/tree/v1) library for Material design [Bottom navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html) and the problem is that its selecting first item by default and there is no any function or option to disable default selection.

How can I disable default selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that BottomBar library adds `BOTTOM_BAR_VIEW_ACTIVE` tag to first item. 
So you could create the first item as a dummy item, and then hide it when library finishes loading, you could call:

```
View oldTab = BottomBar.getRootView().findViewWithTag("BOTTOM_BAR_VIEW_ACTIVE");
if(oldTab != null) oldTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can try other lib, i can recommend this one [Ahbottomnavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)
  But it works not good at Android 7

2) If you need to support Android 7: Google already provided BottomNavigation in [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html). It's still not perfect, so i created some [Extation](https://gist.github.com/borichellow/f7dd87dc4c81419efe48d1026b561b98) for it to make more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The selected method doesn't work for me. Resolved it with,
1) add a dummy tab in tabs.xml

```
<tab
        id="@+id/dummy"/>
```

2) in your mainactivity after bottombar initialization,

```
BottomBarTab dummy = bottomBar.getTabWithId(R.id.dummy);
dummy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```